# How to avoid keeping html elements when saving text from a content editable div

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a content editable div where users can enter their bio and then save the information. I use a form submit and the data I submit is `$('#bio').html()` where the bio tag has the attribute content editable. All of this works very well unless the user hits enter and then it creates a div tag and/or a `<br>`, which are saved as the user's bio and then displayed with the html elements intact, which looks sloppy.

I am looking for either for some way of saving only the text or a way of display only the text. Ideally, I would like to be able to keep the new line without displaying the `<div>` or `<br>`.

If this is at all useful, I am using Ruby-on-Rails 3.

Thanks, Welles

Comment: Is there some reason you're submitting the html of a div and not using a textarea? The situation you describe is exactly what those are for.

Comment: No, there is actually not a reason I'm doing so. I'm going to try using a textarea and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: So the goal is to let the user edit his bio (if he clicks edit) but in all other cases display it normally. So what happens is that on click, I set the attribute contentEditable to true so they can edit the `<div>` without having to convert it to a `<textarea>` if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `strip_tags` method in your controller

```
> ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags("<br><div>sample")
> # => "sample"
```

Or if you want the 
 to be converted to "\n"(new line), then do this

```
> "<br>sample".gsub(/<br>/, "\n") 
> "\nsample"
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the `<br>` and `<div>` are gone completely so the text is all squished together

Comment: isn't that what you want ? You must probably use textarea then

Comment: I think in that case, you must store the text with br tags and then show the description with the br tags, which will retain the formatting. But the answer above is the solution to the question which you have asked

Comment: So sorry if I wasn't clear. The issue is that instead of displaying `hi <br> I am a developer here` I want to display `hi (new line) I'm a developer here`. Your solution, which is definitely a step in the right direction will return `hi I am a developer here`

Comment: I did not get your example, so you don't want anything which comes after <br> ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I hit enter when I wanted a new line but it submitted it. Corrected now!

Comment: ok fine, in the controller you can use the gsub method and replace with a new line `\n` . I have posted it in my answer